# Copy files in Xcode project during post-build phase?

Tags: xcode

I need to copy a set of files and folders on my development system (say, /Users/me/deploy files/folder1, /Users/me/deploy files/folder2, etc.) into my app bundle as one of the last steps of the build process, after the app has been successfully built inside my Xcode project (Xcode 9.x). These files and folders are not dependencies for building the app, and are needed only during the app run time by my app. In my particualr case, I actually want to copy these folders and files to the root level of the app (i.e., in myApp.app/) instead of into the Contents folder hierarchy (myApp.app/Contents/). I tried to look at the Build Phases section to add a Copy Files action but the presented options are not very clear nor self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had it figured out. Instead of adding them to through the Resource Tag, I defined then under **Build Phases->Copy Files**. The key is to set the **Destination** option to **Wrapper**, which indicates that the files/folders will be copied to the myApp.app folder level.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bundle these files in your app, then you should include them as resources in your project. Adding files after build process doesn't looks like a clean solution. Or maybe provide more details on why you have to do this?

You can add resources from Project Navigator -> Project File -> Targets -> **Resources Tags**

Comment: I have tried what you suggested prior to posting the question. The issue is that the added resources reside in myapp.app/Contents/Resources instead of being able to customize the option so that they will reside in myapp.app. Due to cross-platform compatibility and maintenance issues, I need to have these folders and files to reside at the root folder of the app instead of several levels deep.